# Is there any source, where I can save my rest API data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, server

I'm a front end developer and always I have to dependent on back end developers to save my rest API data.

Is there any source, where I can save my rest API data for temporary basis, so I can show a demo to the client.

Comment: databases? json files?

Comment: I should be able to create entries one by one and want to list all entries on another page/website in JSON format.

Comment: I update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you collect all your read/write operations (ajax request) in one or more service class (data provider) - then you can easily mockup this class. It looks that this is the easiest way to achieve what you want.

When you mockup it, instead of send request, your service will return data (in asynchronous way by some observable or promise object-wrapper (which pretend asynchronous request -) ).

Your mockup can be more sophisticated and try to "save" data in local storage (which is very easy) on pretending POST/PUT and then read them during GET pretending.

In this idea is also good because you don't need to learn any new technology (only javascript)

### UPDATE

I see that you add commetn that you wanna save some data in one page, and read this in another page - for this purposes maybe this service will be helpful http://myjson.com/api (it allow to save you json in the cloud) - you can use it in your mockup (first you "create" empty json by hand, and the using PUT/GET you access it from you app service mockups).

You can also use some encryption to protect your data before sending them to myjson.com (eg. [this](https://github.com/tracker1/cryptico-js))

If you not have internet connection, you can also try to locally set up json-server (similar to myjson.com) using for egzample [this](https://github.com/clue/docker-json-server) (it use docker for simple and quick set up). And then run locally your both sites (which have mockuped services which use that json-server).

Comment: @RacilHilan no - you can run your site without internet connection - because all data you write in browser localstorage

Comment: How can you *run your site without internet connection*? Perhaps you mean to run the HTML/JavaScript files from a local folder on your computer? That will only work if your website is a pure HTML/JavaScript site. If you have a backend though, it is more likely that you have a web application (e.g. PHP, .Net, etc), in which case you will need an internet connection unless you also set up a web server on your demo computer (so technically, you take your dev computer, which is not always recommended).

Comment: @RacilHilan - of course i mean: pure html/css/js rich client (the author in fact ask about this kind application I guess - in other case why he "don't wanna have backend" ?).

Comment: He doesn't want a backend, because he cannot take the backend to a demo. That doesn't mean that the website is a pure JS rich client, but it is possible, in which case your solution is good. But then your suggested myjson.com contradicts that and needs a connection.

Comment: From my experience: usually when people say: rest(ful) API this mean micro-service architecture  and "hard" separation between backend and frontend. How ever non-separated case is also possible. To use myjson.com we need internet - you have right.

Comment: Agree, but not always. I'm currently working on an API that will be called by a PHP website developed by another company. They need to use PHP because they access a backend database other than my web service. In big applications, you may connect to more than one data source. But you're probably right, the OP seems to have the scenario you described.

Comment: Thanks @Kamil!! I'm just looking for something like http://myjson.com/api

Comment: @om. i update my answer again

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kamil

Answer (score 1):

you can use, web SQL, IndexedDb or localStorage all these are available in the browser and you don't have to depend on backend for this.

Comment: And how does the data get into the _clients_ browser?

Comment: @Andreas Showing a demo to the client doesn't necessarily mean on the client's computer. You're likely going to take your own device (laptop or tablet) for the demo.

Comment: Then he would not _"deepened on back end developers"_ as he would be able to setup his own "backend"

Comment: @Andreas and that's what he's asking: *Is there any source, where I can save my rest API data for temporary basis*. Obviously a full fledged backend is an option, although it is likely an overkill for a demo.